# JPA @one-to-many // rewrite stored ID

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I would like to rewrite the stored value for a `@ManyToOne` relationship before writing to the database to mimic the behaviour of some legacy code. Latter stores a unset relationship as `0` instead of `null`. All other values (>0) are regular references.

Is there a way to implement a custom mapping for the `@ManyToOne` value to handle this?

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Content")
public class ContentEntity
    // ..
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ColorID")
    private ColorEntity color;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Color")
public class ColorEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    // ..
}
```

**Database:**

```
    CREATE TABLE `Content` (
        # ..
        `ColorID` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL);
    CREATE TABLE `Color` (
        `ID` VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
        # ..)
```

There is no corresponding entry in the target table with `id:0` but multiple records for `id:>0`

I'm using JPA in a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a column transformer for this purpose:

```
@ColumnTransformer(
    forColumn = "ColorID",
    read = "nullif( ColorID, 0 )",
    write = "coalesce( ?, 0 )"
)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ColorID")
private ColorEntity color;
```

Comment: This seems to work only for `@Basic` types. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-read-and-write is there something similar for `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: You are right and it looks like there is no way to configure this. You could map a basic column and the association, but mark the association as `insertable = false, updatable = false` though and use `@JoinFormula(name = "nullif( ColorID, 0 )")`